# Not able to input in android application through keyboard?

Tags: android

I want to enter username and password in android application through key board but i am not able to do that? please help me out? and give proper solution.
 This is case for all android application.

Comment: You are testing this on emulator?

Comment: yes PC Keyboard. and i am doing on emulator.

Comment: The emulator must not be getting focus thats why you are unable to type through keyboard.Try to gain the focus to the emulator by clicking on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default keyboard support has been removed after ADT 20 update.

you can enable it by yourself by editing the AVD

please check the following URL

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23333/how-can-i-use-my-pcs-keyboard-on-the-android-emulator

Answer (score 2):

Click on the Windows->AVD Manager->

on nice window will appear for manage ur virtual device after that click on the "Edit"

In that u can show "Hardware :" ..... in that click on the "New" button...

under the title of "Property :" Select the "Key Board Support"... and Press "Ok"...

after this u can see that in the "Hardware :" grid... in that select the "Yes".. for key board support....